# How to setup codec, samplerate and bitrate on an audio blob in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, audio, audio-streaming, audio-recording

I just created a blob:

```
const audioBlob = new Blob(audioChunks, { 'type' : 'audio/wav; codecs=0' });
```

and sent it to the backend in base64 format. I saved this into a file named "test.wav" using the following code:

```
await writeFile('./temp/test.wav', Buffer.from(filename.replace('data:audio/wav; codecs=0;base64,', ''), 'base64'), 'base64');
```

On the output "test.wav" file, I get the codec as opus, bitrate=N/A and sample rate=48000. I want to change these values to codec=wav, bitrate=256kbps and sample rate=16000. How to achieve it in node(or angular)?

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-umqjpf) is a link for my frontend code.

Comment: You can't have a 256kbps bitrate on 16kHz uncompressed WAV audio. Assuming mono and 16-bit samples (the usual), your bitrate would be 16000 samples/sec * 2 bytes/sample = 32000 bytes/sec.

Comment: Anyway, please show us more code; where does `audioChunks` come from?

Comment: @AKX just added a link for front end code on stackblitz

Comment: You need to look at the AudioRecorder's `mimeType` attribute. You can't just assume the chunks of data you get in that `dataavailable` callback are something that can be interpreted as PCM WAV, and create a blob with that type. For instance, I see `audio/webm;codecs=opus`, i.e. OPUS in a WebM container. Once you have data in a well-known format, you can use a transcoder such as ffmpeg to convert it to another.

Comment: Which mimetype should I use to get a wav output instead of opus? audio/wav or audio/x-wav is not supported it says.

Comment: You simply might not be able to get uncompressed audio out of MediaRecorder. This seems to enumerate some of the supported types for Chrome. https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/third_party/blink/web_tests/fast/mediarecorder/MediaRecorder-isTypeSupported.html

Comment: Blog post about what you want to do: https://addpipe.com/blog/using-recorder-js-to-capture-wav-audio-in-your-html5-web-site/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This line just provides mime information but doesn't affect the actual output

```
const audioBlob = new Blob(audioChunks, { 'type' : 'audio/wav; codecs=0' });
```

To select correct audio codec and bitrate please start recording with following options

```
var options = {
  audioBitsPerSecond : 128000,
  mimeType : 'audio/ogg'
}
var mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, options);
```

As far as I know ogg codec is supported by default in WebRTC, so it is cross browser compatible

Later, on the backend side, you will need to transform `ogg` audio stream to anything else you want using for example [fluent-ffmpeg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fluent-ffmpeg)